# how to get the number, message and datetime and display to grid

Tags: vb.net, at-command

Hi i am developing an application receive SMS, i have experience using the AT COMMANDS by sending an SMS. how am i going to get the sender #, message and the dateTime of the text.

```
port.Write("AT+CNMI=2,1,0,0,1")
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
        port.Write("AT+CMGF=1")
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
        port.Write("AT+CMGL=" & "ALL")
        Thread.Sleep(1000)
        receivedData = port.ReadExisting
```

i want to show all the message in my datagrid just like the picture below, but i have no idea what to do.

```
dgv.Rows.Add(New String() {"", "", ""})
```

[image]

Comment: What is the format of the data that you want to split?

Comment: i want to see the message inside my GSM modem and put it to my DataGridView

Comment: What is the format of "the message inside your GSM modem" that you want to split? Post some examples or explain the format.

Comment: i have added a picture inside my GSM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that receivedData contains a string like this

> GLOBE Your balance is something 8/21/2015 7:20:35 AM

and that the name/number can contain no spaces, you can separate the three parts like this

```
Dim startMessage As Integer = receivedData.IndexOf(" ")
Dim endMessage As Integer = receivedData.Substring(0, receivedData.Length - 17).LastIndexOf(" ")
Dim id, message, timestamp As String 
If startMessage >=0 AndAlso endMessage > startMessage Then
    id = receivedData.Substring(0, startMessage)
    message = receivedData.Substring(startMessage + 1, endMessage - startMessage - 1).Trim
    timestamp = receivedData.Substring(endMessage + 1)
    dgv.Rows.Add({id, message, timestamp})
End If
```

Comment: i have change the title of my question. thank you also for this wonderful idea.

Comment: @Bombards I edited my answer to illustrate how the values could be added to a `DataGridView`.

Comment: +1 yes it was helpful and working fine. but how can i read the 3 of the message i think port.readexisting is wrong it only replies rss^ something like that.

Comment: @Bombards If you have a question about how to read data from a serial(?) port, I suggest you post that as a new question.